# How Do I Post an Alamofire JSON Request on button press?

Tags: ios, json, xcode, swift, alamofire

I am attempting to build a simple iOS app that features a login but first I want to make it so that pressing the "Continue" button on sign up posts data to the REST api. I can't successfully bind it to a button press for some reason. The code below doesn't know what inputboxes is. I ctr+dragged the button then added it in.

```
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON
import UIKit


class SignUpViewController: UIViewController {
    var onButtonTapped : (() -> Void)? = nil

    @IBOutlet weak var usernametextfield: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordtextfield: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var emailtextfield: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var loginMessage: UILabel!

    @IBAction func continueButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

        // POST requests dont need a response!
        Alamofire.request(.POST, endpoint, parameters: inputboxes)

    }

    lazy var json : JSON = JSON.null
    let endpoint = "anyapi.com/api/users"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        digestUser()
    }

    func digestUser() {

        let passwordInput = self.passwordtextfield.text
        let usernameInput = self.usernametextfield.text
        let emailInput = self.emailtextfield.text


        let inputboxes: [String:AnyObject] = [
            "hashword": passwordInput!,
            "username": usernameInput!,
            "email": emailInput!
        ]
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Edit: Alamofire wasn't working properly because I forgot to include: "https://" before the URL

Comment: Hi @Natu, I think your title is deceiving a bit. You seem to be having a problem with Binding the action of a button to a method and not an issue with Alamofire.

Comment: Not as far as I could tell...I had a problem with both and the title says both, no?

Comment: Hi @Natu. From your description I had the feeling that you have the problem with binding ONLY. If you have both problems then the title is okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare `inputboxes` as instance variable below your `outlets`: `var inputboxes: [String:AnyObject] = [:]` and it should work.

Comment: it didn't compile still. My button seems to be the problem

Comment: Actually, it compiles, it just says signal SIGABT before I get to the view controller with this code and stops on my phone then points to my appdeligate file

Comment: Check the console message.

Comment: Some long thing about constraints Maybe my UI is just messed up http://paste.ofcode.org/33rtpnGPz54EuzFArpmjED

Comment: Problem:     ** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<Raptroop.SignUpViewController 0x136eba870> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key continueButton.'

Comment: It looks like you have an outlet setted in your storyborad for continueButton. Go in storyboard select the button, go to outlets in the right panel and and remove the extra outlet.

Comment: thanks I did now everything compiles smooth just that there's no post sent out to my api :(

Comment: Well `digestUser` should be called in `continueButtonPressed` method because you want to take the data when you press the button not when the view loads. And make sure that `continueButtonPressed` is called when you press the button, use `print` for that or the debugger. Also you should check you some iOS tutorials especially on objects lifecycles and on storyboards.

Comment: Very very very much appreciated

Comment: Edit: To those following this thread, fixed the alamo issue. added https:// before the URL

Answer (score 2):

```
    Alamofire.request(.POST, BASE_URL , parameters: parameters as? [String : AnyObject])
        .responseJSON { response in
            if let JSON = response.result.value {
                    print("Success with JSON: \(JSON)")
                }
         }
```

Comment: let parameters:NSDictionary = ["key1":"Value1","Key2":"Value2"]

Comment: both are not working at the moment - I just don't know where to put the button pressed section and that seems to be the issue

Comment: is your inputboxes have data. please check because calling digestUser() from didload and when you enter text into UITextField then inputboxes should have some value.

Answer (score 1):

Try to declare inputboxes outside function so it is accessible in the whole class.